# Reg. Magento site deployment in AWS

Tags: magento2, varnish, redis, elasticsearch, aws

I am new to magento stack, I have a requirement of deploying a magento based e-commerce in AWS.
This site is expected to have 100,000 hits in first couple of months and within an year expected to get about a million hits/month.

Initially i thought of going with a EC2 t3.medium (2Core&4GB) for WEBSERVER and RDS db.t3.small(MySQL) for Database. So far it is fine.

My Query is, in magento docs it is specified that we need to have VARNISH and REDIS for getting better performance.

If i install varnish + Apache httpd + Redis in my EC2 will it be a overkill in t3.medium?

Say If  i have a compute optimized instance c5.xlarge(4Core 10ECU 8GB), Is is fine to load these 3 in one monolithic server?

More over for better product searching, in docs it is specified to use ElastiSearch how we can configure this?

Please suggest me how i can architect this.

Answer (score 1):

if you are really looking for best performance, then you need to install your stack on separate servers.

- varnish
- frontend
- admin
- redis ElastiCache service
- ELK stack - use instance for better view and maintenance
- RDS

having this you can easily add another instance when load goes high, in autoscaling group.
then you dont care about traffic or sales.

Comment: If you want to make setup and usage of Varnish easier, I advise that you install one of the official Varnish Software images. See: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/seller-profile?id=263c0208-6a3a-435d-8728-fa2514202fd0

Comment: @ThijsFeryn the link you posted is for paid image, this is very bad idea, always avoid vendor lock, install varnish as a package. varnish is free, why do i need to pay for it??

Comment: these images are fully maintained, get automatic updates, they are tuned and have various components preset. It also allows you to use Varnish Enterprise, which has a lot more extra capabilities, without paying an upfront license.

If you want to set it up yourself, I see no issue with that. If you want the people who develop Varnish, manage the image for you with the potential for extra capabilities, this can be a very compelling case.

See https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/ for the enterprise features.

Comment: this is stupid idea, if you building ^ cloud infrastructure on your own...

Comment: Depends on your use case, skill set, project timeline, budget ... Let's just say that the term "stupid" is relative. If it were "stupid", Cloud marketplaces would not exist, yet they do. I'm not saying this is the perfect solution for everyone, but it does serve a purpose. Let's just agree that there's not one truth.